# Unable to make Jdbc Connection with Sql server Using Windows Authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jsp, jdbc

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.sql.*"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%!Connection connection = null; %>
    <%
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.1:51317;databaseName=D1E_DERIVE;integratedSecurity=true;"); 
    System.out.println("connection :" + connection);
    connection.close();
    %>
    <%=connection%>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Error :

```
    HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 28
    
    type Exception report
    
    message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 28
    
    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
    
    exception 
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 28
    
    25: <%!Connection connection = null; %>
    26: <%
    27: Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    28:  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.1:51317;databaseName=D1E_DERIVE;integratedSecurity=true;");
    29:  //connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.1:51317;databaseName=D1E_DERIVE","dev","black");
    30:  
    31: System.out.println("connection :" + connection);
    
    
    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    
    
    
    root cause 
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext([B[I[BI[B[I[ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)I
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:120)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    
    
    
    root cause 
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext([B[I[BI[B[I[ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)I
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext(Native Method)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.GenerateClientContext(AuthenticationJNI.java:51)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.SSPIData(SQLServerConnection.java:1948)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2333)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1929)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1917)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1061)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
        java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:91)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

#### Note

```
I have copied the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` at `c:/windows/system32`, then also I am getting the above exception. I am using the tomcat and IDE is STS, even I have also copied the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in bin folder of Tomcat. I am running the tomcat server with the IDE.
```

Comment: point -Djava.library.path to a folder which contains sqljdbc_auth.dll.

Comment: I have added that in VM arguments of tomcat then also the same error is coming..!

Comment: It looks like the JDBC driver version doesn't match with the sqljdbc_auth.dll version. Make sure that both are from the same release, and that there is no other sqljdbc.jar or sqljdbc4.jar on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Mark Rotteveel My problem has been solved...!